# Suppress unused function warning in JSLint

Tags: jslint

I have a JS function within a larger script that updates a progress bar in a web page:

```
function Funktion(t) {
  'use strict';
  var value,
    max,
    go;
  go = setInterval(animate, t);
  value = 0;
  max = 100;
  go = 0;
  function animate() {
    if (value >= max) {
      clearInterval(go);
      return;
    }
    value += 1;
    document.getElementById('progress').value = value;
    document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = value;
    if (value === max) {
      clearInterval(go);
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: *Please assume all relevant variables are properly defined and initialized.* The script as a whole functions properly. JSLint complains `Unused 'animate'.   function animate() {`. I've tried suppressing this warning with a combination of `/*global go: true */` and `/*global animate */`. Is there a way to suppress this warning without hacking into the JSLint rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even easier than I initially thought. You just need to define the function before you use it.

```
/*jslint white:true, browser:true */

function Funktion(t) {
  'use strict';
  var value,
    max,
    go;

  function animate() {
    if (value >= max) {
      clearInterval(go);
      return;
    }
    value += 1;
    document.getElementById('progress').value = value;
    document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = value;
    if (value === max) {
      clearInterval(go);
    }
  }

  go = setInterval(animate, t);
  value = 0;
  max = 100;
  go = 0;
}
```

JSLint is very particular about defining things before they're used. If you call a function you define later in the file, eg, it'll complain.

<strike>So you were using `animate` before JSLint knew what it was. It's *very* procedural in its evaluation.</strike>

So you were using an undefined `animate` initially, which JSLint probably should have yelled at instead of allowing you to end run around `var` declaration using a `function` declaration later.

Then you "re-defined" `animate` (from JSLint's pov) as a function, and *never used it*. Har har.

You get a much better error message if you try [your code (with a few JSLint directives added)](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sRvKvpzE) at the more recently updated engine at [jslint.com](http://jslint.com):

> 'animate' is out of scope.

That error message points at the `go = setInterval(animate, t);` line, which is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out for unused variables:

```
/*jshint unused: true, node: true */
```

Try this one out for unused variables that come as parameters (use this one with the above one):

```
/*jslint unparam: true, node: true */
```